# How can I add fixed background just to this section? [demo included]

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add a fixed background to ONLY this section of my web-page.
When someone scroll down to another section, I'll add background color, not image.
I dont know how to explain this, so I made a demo on my website:
[demo](http://csgotale.com/stackoverflow-demo/)
[image explanation](https://prnt.sc/cziyad)

**I already tried this:**

```
.cd-fixed-bg {
    min-height: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}
.cd-fixed-bg.cd-bg-1 {
    background-image: url(" IMAGE URL IS HERE ");
}
```

**My html code (without this css above this):**

[image]

That didn't work execly on way I wanted, so I uploaded demo with that too:
[demo](http://csgotale.com/stackoverflow-demo/index-with-my-try.html)
PS. Ignore russian phone images, I was just testing something.
I tried some other css tricks but nothing worked correctly.

Thanks.

Since the question is answered correctly, demo was removed. Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand why I'm getting negative ratings? At least, add a comment so I can know what to improve in question...

Comment: Still don't understand why receiving negative reputation, guys can you provide any comment about your negative reputation? 
Question is answered already...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it's work fine: http://csgotale.com/stackoverflow-demo/index-with-my-try.html

but, add to your **html,body** and **h1** `margin: 0; padding: 0;`

If you wanna make Parallax Effect, i do it here: http://codepen.io/powro01/details/pEBBgR/

Comment: Or you can use reset.css :)

Comment: I did :) 
×
Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you won't be able to achieve this effect using only CSS; you will need some amount of JS code.

They're not quite what you're looking for I'd recommend looking at these to see if they help:

https://github.com/razorfish/Parallax-JS

https://github.com/cyntss/Parallax-img-scroll